# PHP - How to globalize CRUD classes for different pages?

Tags: php, crud

**Kind note: Practicing PHP**

I got the CRUD library from this repo: https://github.com/rorystandley/mysqli-crud-php-oop.

I setup the database, connected to to it and everything is great. I am only unaware of how to use this globally?

I have different pages for different data tables, I see it not logical to create multi "insert.php" files for each page.

**Insert.php:**

```
<?php
include('class/mysql_crud.php'); // Contains the server info (locahost, user, pass, table)
$db = new Database();
$db->connect();
$data = $db->escapeString("name5@email.com"); // Escape any input before insert
$db->insert('CRUDClass',array('name'=>'Name 5','email'=>$data));  // Table name, column names and respective values
$res = $db->getResult();  
print_r($res);
```

I believe `include();` won't solve it as each page has different data to pass around.

Should I create a condition for "if that page, then pass this data"??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Something like a simple ORM might be helpful, but if it's a simple project you can also create a seperate class that contains the methods for insertion into the table and call the method you need from the pages. (take a look at illuminate/database, https://github.com/illuminate/database)

Comment: Why do you escape values? You should be using prepared statements

Comment: This is a terrible, extremely horrendous library. I recommend you delete it and forget about it. Erase its existence from your mind. Please, I beg you, do not use it for anything, even for learning purposes.

Comment: @Dharman Why? why is it that bad?

Comment: @kks21199 The project is a dashboard for data entry. I'll take a look at your recommendation...it looks difficult but I'll give it tries. Thank you

Comment: The library I linked is part of laravel, so if you face any issues, you should be able to find help quite easily. https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-illuminate-database-with-eloquent-in-your-php-app-without-laravel--cms-27247

Comment: It's bad because it contains blaring SQL injection. It uses mysqli for reasons unknown. It has a very messy codebase, really bad design, poor error handling, etc.